# Const does not Exist in React

Tags: reactjs, constants

I have the following code in react. The style corresponds to the names of the markers imported at the top.

```
  import {markerColored, markerUnColored, markerDefault} from './markers.js';

  ....

  render() {
    if(this.props.colored){
      const style = markerColored;
    }else if(this.props.unSelected){
      const style = markerUnColored;
    }else{
      const style = markerDefault;
    }

   return (
       <div className=" hint hint--html hint--info hint--top " style={style}>
          {this.renderMarkerIcon()}
       </div>
   );
 }
}
```

When I run the following above, I get the error:

```
  Uncaught ReferenceError: style is not defined
```

However, if I were to do something like this, I get no error:

```
   render() {

   const style = this.props.colored? markerColored : markerUnColored 

   return (
       <div className=" hint hint--html hint--info hint--top " style={style}>
          {this.renderMarkerIcon()}
       </div>
   );
```

The problem is I have 3 styles I want to use. Why does the top code tell me the const style doesn't exist when it goes through the conditional loops? Is there something trivial I'm missing?

Comment: `const` is blocked scoped. `style` is not accessible outside the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` are always specific to a scope. Here the scope is `if` and `else`. After that it will be undefined.

Try this

```
let style = markerDefault
if(this.props.colored){
   style = markerColored;
}else if(this.props.unSelected){
   style = markerUnColored;
}
```